# Json Convert de serialize string to data table behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have to deserialize stirng to datatable. I used the following code `dTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);` it works. I have calculated the time taken for deserializing process, for first time of deserializing it takes 70 ms. when i refresh the page and calculate the same it takes 0 ms for deserializing, What happens for the first time and second. Waiting for kind reply to proceed further.

Comment: You need to add some more context to this questions. In particular, we need to see some more code that shows when that assignment is executed.

Comment: @Anton I'am trying to deserialize this json string `[{  "Asset_Description" : "Test MongoDB without Memcache", "Asset_File_Name" : "3084_1_chip.jpg", "Asset_Name" : "Chip" },  { "Asset_Description" : "Test MongoDB without memcache", "Asset_File_Name" : "3085_1_desktop.jpg",  "Asset_Name" : "Desktop"}]` to datatable using this code `DataTable dTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);` it's getting deserialised but time was my consideration.

Answer (score 0):

On your first run, the time took longer because the hosting process is just created and run. On your second attempt, the debugger has then improved its performance because the hosting process is still running which helps in debugging optimization.